# Opera and IE does not attribute css text-decoration correctly

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout, opera

Using Opera 11 and IE 9, it seems that these two browsers do not attribute the CSS text-decoration style correctly. This works 100% in Chrome, FireFox and Safari. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

*The Wrong Effect:*

[image]

*The Right Effect:*

[image]

Here's the CSS:

```
#main_title {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#main_title a {
    color: #000;
}

#main_title_accent {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background: #ff9935;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="main_title">
    <a href="home">Text <span id="main_title_accent">Goes</span> Here</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give `display:inline-block` to the `#main_title_accent`.

Read more at [w3c: 16.3.1 - text-decoration property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#lining-striking-props)

Relevant quote

> Note that text decorations are not
>   propagated to floating and absolutely
>   positioned descendants, nor to the
>   contents of atomic inline-level
>   descendants **such as inline blocks** and
>   inline tables.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/qp32H/1/

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you Gaby.